# Rendering Technique in OpenGL

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es

I want to enable rendering in specified points (I am holding the collection of points in array) and disable rendering on rest of OpenGL layer

can any one help me to get out of this problem for iPhone!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of stencil in opengl for iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603414/usage-of-stencil-in-opengl-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenGL ES 2.0, you can use the stencil buffer to mask those areas.

Comment: Thanks for the response,as i am new to opengl unable to understand the functionality of stencil buffer!!! Any simple example to get me out of this Issu ...